# Calling Method so that program doesn't get blocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I need to call SendEmail() in my C# code below so that my program doesn't get blocked due to SendEmail() method taking a lot of time and or failing.

Here's my C# code:(I'm using .Net 4.5)

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    DoSomething();
    SendEmail();
}
```

Can I achieve the same using following please?Or is there any other better approach ?Is using async/await a better approach for achieving this?

```
public void MyMethod()
        {
            DoSomething();

            try
            {   
                string emailBody = "TestBody";
                string emailSubject = "TestSubject";

                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new System.Threading.WaitCallback(SendEmailAlert), arrEmailInfo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log error message
            }

        }

        private void SendEmailAlert(object state)
        {
            string[] arrEmailnfo = state as string[];
            MyClassX.SendAlert(arrEmailnfo[0], arrEmailnfo[1]);
        }
```

And In case I need to make SendEmailAlert() method as fire and forget, I can use code like this Would that be correct? ---->

```
Task.Run(()=> SendEmailAlert(arrEmailInfo));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Look into async/await

Comment: You can use threading, but it's probably better to use async/await for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async await can definitely help you. When you have CPU-bound work to do asynchronously, you can use `Task.Run()`. This method can be "awaited" so that the code will resume after the task is done.

Here's what I would do in your case:

```
public async Task MyMethod()
{
    DoSomething();

    try
    {   
        string emailBody = "TestBody";
        string emailSubject = "TestSubject";

        await Task.Run(()=> SendEmailAlert(arrEmailInfo));

        //Insert code to execute when SendEmailAlert is completed.
        //Be aware that the SynchronizationContext is not the same once you have resumed. You might not be on the main thread here
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log error message
    }

}

private void SendEmailAlert(string[] arrEmailInfo)
{
    MyClassX.SendAlert(arrEmailnfo[0], arrEmailnfo[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.And in case I need to make SendEmailAlert() method as fire and forget, I can remove the await keyword and use it like below..would that be correct? ----> Task.Run(()=> SendEmailAlert(arrEmailInfo));

Comment: @Vineetv yes, in this case you can remove the await!